# How to compile dynamic virtual channel c++ example from MSDN

Tags: c++

On MSDN there is an [example in C++ on how to create Dynamic virtual channel plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My problem is that I don't know how to compile it.

Do I need to create an ATL project and in `main.cpp` copy-and-paste the code found on msdn? What do I call the project? If I create ATL project with name `DVCPlugin`, than Visual studio 2008 automatically creates `DVCPlugin_i.h file`, otherwise I don't have that file.

`tsvirtualchannels.h` is part of Windows 7 SDK so at least with that include I don't have a problem.

One of the errors I am getting is this:

> `&CLSID_DVCSamplePlugin` not recognized identifier

I tried to create ATL project with the name `DVCSamplePlugin` but I received the same message as above.

Any suggestions I need to do to be able to compile that source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some code for testing Remote desktop connection -

> There is an "echo" listener that is implemented by the Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) client, which is always present and listening for incoming connections. When you are writing the server side of a dynamic virtual channel (DVC) module, as a quick test you can open an endpoint named "ECHO". Any write to a channel that is instantiated from this endpoint will result in the receipt of the same data.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Such projects are usually included in some SDK. And this one seems to be part of [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949)

Update: After a critique from Tim (see below), i've decided to add these links with MSDN information -
[Remote Desktop Services. TS-Teleport: Sample Instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/09/19/ts-teleport-sample-instructions.aspx) and 
[Remote Desktop Services Blog. Dynamic Virtual Channels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/09/20/dynamic-virtual-channels.aspx)

Comment: @Tim - in what way? If you download SDK there must be a complete project to be compiled with all headers needed. How are you going to compile it the other way?

Comment: Not every piece of sample code published on the MSDN exists as a complete project in the SDK. This DVC sample COM object is not part of the SDK download.

Comment: To download SDK and look through the samples is a general rule of MSDN. If it is not included, search MSDN or Google for it, For example "Dynamic Virtual Channels (DVC) Sample (Windows Embedded Compact 7)" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg155299.aspx

Comment: @SChepurin: Thank you for your answer update. I believe it will be useful (I will check it tommorow).

Answer (score 3):

It took me a couple of hours, but I got the source for the client plugin to build using VS 2012. Here were my steps.

1. Start a new ATL Project named `DVCPlugin`. Select the option for a DLL.
2. Choose support for COM+ and check the box for the Object Registrar.
3. Add a file named `GUID.cpp` to the DVCPlugin project. include `stdafx.h` in this file.
4. ATL gave me a class named CompReg, which had its own IDL entries and GUID. I needed to associate that GUID with the `CDVCSamplePlugin` class.
5. In `DVCPlugin.cpp`, add the include for `<tsvirtualchannels.h>` to the top.
6. Paste the rest of the sample code after the definition of `DllInstall()`.
7. Change the line `DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_PLUGIN)` to `DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_DVCPLUGIN)`.
8. It looks like building the solution silently runs the registry script in the `DVCPlugin.rgs` file. I had to change the threading model to Free, though.
9. If mstsc.exe is 64-bit, you need a 64-bit plugin dll for the dynamic discovery to work.